# Complexity of Finding Every Cycle in a Graph?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

What's the best asymptotic complexity of finding every cycle in a simple, directed graph?

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this online. I'm able to use DFS for cycle detection, but I'm looking to determine the weight of each cycle in a graph, thus I'd like to be able to determine them all.

Comment: A graph could have exponentially many cycles.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Exponentially in terms of? The edges?

Comment: To clarify, I'm taking it as granted the graph is simple.

Comment: The complete graph on $n$ vertices contains $(n-1)!/2$ Hamiltonian cycles alone.

Comment: In fact, the problem of counting cycles is hard in the sense that a polynomial-time algorithm for it would imply $\mathsf P = \mathsf{NP}$, which is a strong indication that no (theoretically) efficient algorithm exists. There is a chapter about counting complexity which is not too hard to read (given you have some prior experience with complexity theory) in the Arora/Barak textbook [here](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/).

Comment: You might be more likely to find a useful solution if you tell what problem you're actually trying to solve (e.g., what you're going to do with the list of all cycles).